# Why are YouTube videos having so much trouble?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, flash, streaming, youtube

I am getting sick and tired of this. Youtube, in my browser, Google Chrome 26.0.14.1065, on my MacBook Pro, is running so slowly. I am at the point where I can download a 10 min video before it loads completely to play on the player.

At times, it will just start playing 3 secs in, and then freeze. It won't even load anymore. Other times it will be like "OHHHH you wanted me to play that? Ok." and it will load the fastest I've seen, just because I clicked somewhere on the bar. Most of the time to get it to load I have to keep refreshing.

What's MOST infuriating, is after it has loaded up to a certain point (I paused it and let it load), then when I try to play it and click on a point, it will FORGET it loaded that point and start all over again.

Rarely, but still an occurring thing, it will pretend it's loaded, but it really chopped the video in half and you must refresh to start alllll over.

I installed the plugin SmartVideo For Youtube, but it's not really helping that much.

Now, I have relatively slow internet, 6.8 mbs download, 1 mbs upload, or something like that. BUT, the internet doesn't seem to be the problem, because the internet loads pages pretty fast AND videos on other sites load give me NO PROBLEM.

Like, I can watch a 30 min HQ tutorial on VideoCopilot.net, but I can't watch a 3 minute video on youtube (which is STILL loading in another tab as I type this)

Anyone know what the problem is here?

Also, thanks to SmartVideo, I can see that it keeps saying "Buffering is stalled, will stop"

Also, I have no idea how to use SV correctly, what's the difference between hitting the play button on a YT vid, and hitting the one on SV?

Update: This helped, [Why is YouTube buffering/loading behavior so horrible in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/586236/why-is-youtube-buffering-loading-behavior-so-horrible-in-chrome)
But it's still nowhere near as fast as another site. I can watch Vimeo, VideoCopilot, and Nostalgia Critic with no problem

The link DID however seem to fix the unstability of loading on YouTube.

Comment: I've been having issues with YouTube all day today on my Windows machine and Android phone.  I would then assume it's something to do with their servers and not your machine.

Comment: Maybe, but it's been happening for more than just today. Maybe a week or 2

Comment: try installing flash plugin externally rather than using chrome's built in flash